# Allocators: how are the standard containers expected to work internally?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, allocator

As an example for this question, I'll use `std::vector`.
Its definition from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) follows:

```
template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class vector;
```

As expected, if `T` is its type, the allocator should be biased towards `T`.
Anyway, **the code below compiles with no errors (at least, using GCC) and runs**:

```
#include<vector>
#include<memory>
#include<string>

struct S {
    int i;
    double d;
    std::string s;
};

int main() {
    std::allocator<int> alloc;
    std::vector<S, std::allocator<int>> v{alloc};
    v.push_back(S{});
}
```

Here, I'm creating a *vector* of *S* by using an allocator focused on *int*.

Is it legal code? Should I expect undefined behavior? What else?
I don't fully understand what the magic behind that and why the STL lets the users do that.
On the other side, things like `rebind` are mentioned only in the documentation of `std::list` and I don't know if they are meant also for such a case.

In other therms, if it works I'd like to know why it works (is it `rebind` behind that?), otherwise I'd like to know why it is allowed.

Comment: As a side-note: you can observe the effect of type `rebind`, by deriving your own allocator class as `class ValidAllocator : public std::allocator<S>` and `class InvalidAllocator : public std::allocator<int>`. By using them instead of their templated base class, the compiler can't rebind the `<int>` and starts throwing errors. So in practice it might be reasonable to rely on the compiler - eigher it throws errors or it takes care of type-rebinding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Table 98 -- Allocator-aware container requirements says in its first row:

> *Requires:* `allocator_type::value_type` is the same as `X::value_type`

Violation of a *Requires* clause by the client code results in undefined behavior.

gcc and VS do not detect this error.  They allow the code to work by rebinding the allocator to the appropriate type.  libc++ actively detects this error with a `static_assert`.

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LVYEHfVIGoyZsii8

All three implementations of `vector` are valid in this regard.

The rationale for the libc++ active detection of this error is to find your errors for you faster (and at compile time).  It would be a bad thing if in a large program you had two vectors:  `vector<int, some_allocator<int>>` and `vector<int, some_allocator<long>>` and the program logic assumed these were the same type.

Comment: ha! exactly. I really don't see how either yours or my answer are "opinionated".

Comment: How does it work for `std::function` instead? In such a case, the allocator's value type is unspecified even in the documentation. Moreover, the allocator is not part of the type itself, instead it is a constructor argument.

Comment: @skypjack:  This part of the `std::function` specification is what I diplomatically refer to as "semantics-free".  (it isn't a compliment).  The current libc++ implementation of `std::function` completely ignores its allocator argument for several of the places it uses it.  In the one place it doesn't, it internally rebinds the allocator to whatever it needs:  https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/functional#L1754-L1780  Future std specifications may do a better job (or may not).

Comment: Your last paragraph, even tho VS doesn't detect the error (but rebinds), it does detect an attempt to use the two as they were the same type. Err C2440, so how it is really different from lic++?

Comment: @HowardHinnant Interesting, there are a few other classes that type-erase the type of the allocators as `std::function` does, as an example `std::promise`. It seems to me that you don't like so much this choice, it would be interesting to go deeply in the topic indeed.

Comment: @mainactual:  VS/gcc delay the error detection as long as possible.  libc++ detects the error as soon as possible.  Imho, the latter makes it more likely to detect the error today, instead of next month, while the code the programmer is writing is still in his biological L1 cache.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it works, which kind of surprises me, but:

You're breaking a contract. `allocator` must fulfill the requirements for `allocator<T>`, and to [cite cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator), this includes:

> `a.allocate(n)` | allocates storage suitable for `n` objects of type `T`, but does not construct them. May throw exceptions.

Which `std::allocator<int>` for `S` doesn't do, as `sizeof(int)!= sizeof(S)`.

So,

> I'd like to know why it is allowed.

It's not allowed. It's just nothing your compiler can detect.

@AlbertoM [adds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256098/allocators-how-are-the-standard-containers-expected-to-work-internally/35256264?noredirect=1#comment58231022_35256264):

> To add a quote from cppreference, in the `std::vector` page: " the behavior is undefined if `Allocator::value_type` is not the same as `T`.", `T` being the value type of the vector.

Ie. in your case, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: So, should I expect an undefined behavior? Not so complete an answer indeed. Not sure that's right with so few details...

Comment: Well, yes, you're breaking a contract, and that means that you don't really know what'll happen.

Comment: I don't understand what contract I'm violating. The method `allocate` of `std::allocator<int>` is not affected by the fact that I'm using it within a `std::vector` of something else and, as far as that vector rebinds internally the allocator, everything works fine. That's why I'm asking if this is the case. The proposed links and information do not confirm nor contradict anything, so... Quite opinion-based an answer, indeed. You'd have the same problem with a `std::function` and here your reasoning would fail... What's the right type for it? How could it work?

Comment: To add a quote from cppreference, in the std::vector page: " the behavior is undefined if Allocator::value_type is not the same as T.", T being the value type of the vector.

Comment: Compilers/libs **can** detect this error.  But they are not required to.  libc++ does: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LVYEHfVIGoyZsii8

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Naturally, the question than becomes: Should they detect and complain, or silently rebind?

Comment: @Deduplicator Other than that question another one arises from that answer. I'm going to create a new question, indeed...

Comment: @HowardHinnant You can add a response with that example, I think it definitely close the question with the comment from the documentation posted by Alberto M (I don't know how I missed it!!).

Comment: @skypjack I don't see how citing *"storage **suitable** for `n` objects **of type `T`**"* is opinion-based. Storage for 10 `int` isn't suitable for 10 `S` instances.

Comment: @skypjack The note about Allocator::value_type was added to cppreference _after_ this answer was posted :)

Comment: @cpplearner Well, maybe someone has read the question and he has felt guilty!! :-)